# How to solve (×-4)^x ≠ 0

Tags: inequality

I know it seems quite simple but I'm struggling to understand this equation.. 
Basically the solution is x>4 but I would say x<4 and x>4 because if I try to put 3 as x the result would be : 
(3-4)^3 = -1 which isn't 0
Or if I substitute 2 to x :
(2-4)^2 = 4 which isn't 0 
The only one that as 0 as a solution is 4 :
(4-4)^4 = 0

I just don't get it .. 
Someone will help me please? 
Thanks in advance :)

PS. I'm sorry if the tag isn't proper

Comment: We can't answer the question as long as you don't specify the exponentiation operation that you use. What about exponentiation of a negative ?

Comment: One problem might be that $a^b$ is not well-defined if $a$ is negative and $b$ is not an integer. Thus, $x = 3$ is possible, but (for example) $x = 3.5$ is not. Still, saying that the solution is $x > 4$ is also not good, as you noticed correctly that $x = 3$ would be a solution.

Comment: Basically I found this function in my book : y= 2/(x-4)^x and I have to find the domain.. Which will be : (×-4)^x ≠ 0 but I don't know how to solve it

Comment: We can't define for $x<4 \to (x-4) <0$

Comment: @Khosrotash: this is a little restrictive, at least integer powers of negatives are not hard to define.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're right that $x=3$ solves the equation, but because there's an $x$ in the exponent, your book and/or teacher might exclude negative bases as $a^x$ doesn't behave *nicely* for $a<0$.

More specifically, for an expression of the form $a^x$, or in your case $f(x)^x$, it's possible that they demand $a \ge 0$ or $f(x) \ge 0$. In that case, only $x>4$ would satisfy this demand *and* the equation.

Comment: The problem is that even if I can consider 3 like a solution, if I draw the graph of y= (x-4)^x trough a math-program the result is always x>4 without excluding anything, and I don't get why in theory I can substitute 3 to x and in the graph this option doesn't appear

Comment: It would be hard to graph a single dot, since there would only be a real solution at $x=3$ but not in the direct neighborhood of $x=3$. For this reason, most graphing software probably applies the same restrictions (positive base). Here's [WolframAlpha's plot](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+(x-4)%5Ex+from+-1+to+6).

Comment: Okay but why did you say that if I consider f(x)≥0 the only possible solution would be x>4 when also substituting 2 I obtain a positive solution which is 4 ?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. I was referring to $f(x) = x-4$, the base. So a positive base doesn't mean $x>0$ but $x-4>0 \iff x > 4$; this excludes $x=2$ just as it excludes $x=3$...

Answer (score 0):

In the reals, $a^b=0\iff a=0,b\ge0$, with the possible exception of $0^0$, depending on how you define that.

So $(x-4)^x=0\iff x=4$, and the solution is "all non-negative values of $x$ for which $(x-4)^x$ is defined, but $x=4$".